# How to create an hexagon image in react native

Tags: react-native, react-native-image

I'm trying to make an Image into hexagon in react native but I don't know how to do that.
Here is the expected result:
[hexagon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sSLrk.jpg)

Comment: could you provide an example of the expected result?

Comment: I updated my question and add the expected result.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to create a perfect hexagon Image View using [react-native-shape-image-view](https://github.com/shahen94/react-native-shape-image-view) dependency.

Here is the screenshot:- [image: screenshot]

But it requires following changes before we can use it.

1. change `buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"` to `buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"`
2. change import of **PropTypes** from 'react' to `import PropTypes from 'prop-types'` inside node_modules\react-native-shape-image-view\lib\hexagonView.

You have to change this import in every file where **PropTypes** are used. inside

node_modules\react-native-shape-image-view\lib\

You may face some linking issues in the installation of this dependency but it will work.
Refer Installation instruction at given link of this dependency.